# Send notification mail using Azure Logic Apps in C#

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-logic-apps

How we can send a automatically mail notification on a particular date using Azure Logic App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Recurrence** Trigger to send emails or notifications at a particular time. It gets triggered at the same time every day or the time which you have opted for.
[image]

If you want it to be occurred only once then you can go to **Settings** -> Allow **Concurrency Control** and make **Degree of Parallelism** to 1. By doing this the logic app can just run with one instance.

[image]